# Render Partial Item only if column is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, partial-views

I'm trying to loop over my 'offers' collection in a partial, but each 'offer' has a column 'featured' which is a boolean which defaults to false. I'm trying to loop over the collection and only display the offers which have the featured column set to true.

I currently have:

```
<%= render @offers %>
```

Trying below but comes back with 'undefined method 'featured'

```
<%= render @offers if @offer.featured == true %>
```

Any help would be fantastic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your controller, set up another collection:

```
@featured_offers = Offer.where(featured: true)
```

And render that instead:

```
<%= render @featured_offers %>
```

Answer (score 1):

To correct your **immediate code**, you're calling `.featured` on `@offer` - which doesn't exist.

You'll either need to loop through `@offers` and use logic on `offer`, or use conditions inside the partial (which is highly inefficient):

```
<% @offers.each do |offer| %>
   <%= render offer if offer.featured %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<%= render @offers %>

#_offer.html.erb
<% if offer.featured %>
   This is super inefficient
<% end %>
```

--

`@jason` is correct with his recommendation of using a `where` clause

You may even want to go a step further and set up a [scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope):

```
#app/models/offer.rb
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :featured, -> { where featured: true } 
end

@offers = Offer.featured
```

You can even chain the scope:

```
@offers = Offer.where(user_id: params[:id])

<%= render @offers.featured %>
```